# Maintenance mode and user session

Tags: maintenance-mode

When I put site in maintenance mode and after turn site back all users sessions are not active (is need to log in account), but I put session to work 2 month and it work.

How to prevent users logout when put site in maintenance?

Comment: Did the database change during the maintenance mode? Did you do any updates?

Comment: No, I can use something other to stop access for users to site for some time, but also when make updates the site also is in maintenance. And It also lost  will drop all sessions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is intended behavior, if user does not have "access site in maintenance mode" permission, then user is logged out.

For Drupal 7 take look on [user_menu_site_status_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.module/function/user_menu_site_status_alter/7.x)

For Drupal 8 take look on [Drupal\user\EventSubscriber\MaintenanceModeSubscriber](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21user%21src%21EventSubscriber%21MaintenanceModeSubscriber.php/8.5.x)

Comment: The question was about losing sessions after the Maintenance mode is turned off, not during it.

Comment: Yes, this is the reason why the session is destroyed - the logged-in user visits the website which is in maintenance mode. The user who visits the website after the maintenance mode is turned off will not be logged out.

Comment: Thanks for linked to the code here. This is shocking behavior, does anyone know if there were technical reasons behind doing this? Users lose all content they were working on if they hit "submit" or refresh the form they were working on. I am looking for some discussions around this to understand the "why" a bit better.